# AngularJS $confirmPasswordReset is not a function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up Firebase `confirmPasswordReset` in order to create a custom email action handlers. Here is what I have:

```
app.controller("ResetPass", ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", "$location", function ($scope, $firebaseAuth, $location) {

    $scope.resetMe = function () {
        var newPassword = $scope.user.password;
        var actionCode = $location.search().oobCode;
        var mode = $location.search().mode;
        console.log(actionCode);
        console.log(newPassword);
        console.log(mode);
        var auth = $firebaseAuth();
        auth.$confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword).then(function (resp) {
            console.log("reset pass, done");
            $scope.errMsg = false;
            $location.path('/login.signin');
        }).catch(function (error) {
            $scope.errMsg = true;
            $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
        });
    }

}]);
```

I am refering to the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). I get the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

**Note**: My other Firebase controllers are working, login and registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you gotta change it to this by removing the firebaseauth and replacing it with firebase:

```
app.controller("ResetPass", ["$scope","firebase",  "$location", function ($scope,firebase,  $location) {

    $scope.resetMe = function () {
        var newPassword = $scope.user.password;
        var actionCode = $location.search().oobCode;
        var mode = $location.search().mode;
        console.log(actionCode);
        console.log(newPassword);
        console.log(mode);
        //var auth = $firebaseAuth();
        firebase.auth().confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword).then(function (resp) {
            console.log("reset pass, done");
            //$scope.errMsg = false;
            $location.path('/login.signin');
        }).catch(function (error) {
            $scope.errMsg = true;
            $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
        });
    }

}]);
```